# How to display search bar 'inline' with other elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigational bar with page links but the 'search' bar doesn't go horizontally with other list elements:

**HTML**

```
<header class="nav">
  <ul class="main">
    <li><a href="page1">page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2">page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3">page3</a></li>
    <li> 
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <a href="#" class="button" id="searchbut">Search</a>
      </form> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

li {
  display:inline; 
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: You will also need to set `display: inline` for the form.

Comment: Could you provide an image of what is the final look you want for the search BOX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the form's `display` to `inline-block` in CSS. Block level elements do not allow other elements to be on their horizontal space.

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the form's `display` to `inline`. Since it is by default a block level element, it takes its own space throughout the available width.

```css
nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav">
  <ul class="main">
    <li><a href="page1">page1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page2">page2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page3">page3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <a href="#" class="button" id="searchbut">Search</a>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some examples:

#### basic

```
nav {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

li, li > form {
  display:inline; 
  list-style:none;
}
```

#### right 10px margin except for the last item

```
nav {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

li, li > form {
  display:inline; 
  list-style:none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child > form{
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

#### links on the left search bar in the right

```
nav {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

li, li > form {
  display:inline; 
  list-style:none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child > form{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

li:last-child{
  float:right;
}
```

#### links on the RIGHT search bar in the LEFT

```
nav {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

li, li > form {
  display:inline; 
  list-style:none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li:last-child > form{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(n){
  float:right;
}
li:last-child{
  float:left;
}
```